# Google Map API geocoder language not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I make 2 requests to Google Map API geocoder in different languages:

```js
geocoder.geocode({
    'latLng': latlng,
    'language': 'en'
}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        $address_en.val(results[0].formatted_address);
    }
});

geocoder.geocode({
    'latLng': latlng,
    'language': 'ja'
}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        $address_ja.val(results[0].formatted_address);
    }
});
```

But geocoder **use default language** in both request.

**--- Update: ---**

I don’t see `language` parameter in new [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) ([Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderRequest)).
But it existed earlier.

I found it in [Changelog](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/wiki/JavascriptMapsAPIv3Changelog):

> **3.5** June 8, 2011
>
> Noticeable changes:
>
> - Removed GeocoderRequest’s "language" option

---

Is it possible to do this now?

Answer (score 2):

The `google.maps.GeocoderRequest` object does not have a `language` property.

> The addresses will be returned by the Geocoder using the browser's preferred language setting, or the language specified when loading the API JavaScript using the language parameter. (For more information, see [Localization](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Localization).)

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding